# Генерация всех возможных чисел по списку

Tags: python, python-3.x

Здравствуйте!
Есть список вида

```
list = [8, 4, 5, 4, 1, 7, 2, 2, 8, 1, 2, 6, 3, 9, 9, 1, 8, 2, 5, 1, 3, 9, 7, 7, 2, 1, 9, 4, 4, 8, 4, 8, 6, 9, 2, 2, 8, 6, 1, 3]
```

В списке может быть как больше так и меньше символов. Не могу понять как сделать так чтобы на выходе я получал всевозможные комбинации чисел из списка не менее заданной длины.
Пример вывода для заданной длины 7:

```
 8139714
 9845118
 226624687
 5471344817
 1452236
 ...
```

Comment: Рандомный выбор пробовали?

Comment: itertools.combinations(list, 7) + itertools.combinations(list, 8) ....

Comment: Спасибо за наводку. Сделал при помощи [random.choice(list) for x in range(10)]. Я только изучаю python. Как можно вместо range(10) задать минимальную длину т.е от 7 до 10 скажем?

Comment: а если скажем использовать простой `range(min(L), max(L)+1)`. Останется лишь добавить генерацию всех перестановок начинающихся с нуля(ей)? ну ессно только для питон 3х, либо `xrange` для питон 2х.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Решил пока так, на выходе получаю то что надо. Сильно не пинайте, я только изучаю python

```
import itertools
def group(iterable, count):
    """ Группировка элементов последовательности по count элементов """

    return zip(*[iter(iterable)] * count)

res = list(group(list,10))
nres = list()
nnn = list()
for newr in res:
    t = itertools.permutations(newr)
    nres.append(list(t))
i = 0
for t in nres:
    for w in nres[i]:
        nnn.append(''.join(map(str, w)))
    i+=1

newlist = list(set(nnn))
```